# update 'WSS Username Token' in all requests of a testset at once

Tags: soapui

I have a testsuite in SoapUI NG, and I regularly have to change the credentials for Basic authentication for all requests (about 25).
At this moment I open all requests one by one and remove the  part, and then add the new WSS Username Token.
But there has to be a faster, more efficient way to do this, I guess. But I haven't figured it out yet.
Can anyone give me a hint?
Thanks!

Comment: May be you can try adding the credentials at the interface level and assign to all the test requests.

Comment: I've already fixed the credentials, but when I change them I also have to update the WSS Username Token in the Xml of the request. And it gets annoying to do that for 25 requests ;-)

Comment: Do you mean in soap Header of the requests? then you may remove it from the request and in the preferences, find and  check the tick mark to add WSS to the outgoing requests, the it should solve it.

Comment: @rao, I guess this option is not available in SoapUI NG...

Comment: Have you checked File->Preferences->HTTP Settings-> Authenticate Preemptively ? Click the check box.

Comment: @Rao, it doesn't quite do what I expect it to do, but it works for now. Thanks!